# Tkinter Button Command switches when new Button is used

Tags: python, tkinter

I face an issue which is that my first button is using the second button's command. I have faced this logic error multiple times when trying to create buttons programmatically with different functions, is there a way to resolve this or is this a limitation to Tkinter? The gif below illustrates my issue.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def print_when_clicked(message):
    print(message)

array = ["hi", "bye"]

for i in array:
    tk.Button(root, text=i, command=lambda:print_when_clicked(i)).pack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen in to one of the classic Python traps.  The issue is that the `lambda` captures the `i` variable, NOT the value of `i`.  So, after the loop finishes, `i` is bound to "bye", and both functions use it.

The trick to work around this is to use a fake default argument:

```
for i in array:
    tk.Button(root, text=i, command=lambda i=i:print_when_clicked(i)).pack()
```

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if making the lambda function a separate variable something like
`l = lambda i: print_when_clicked(i)` 
and then using it like
```
for i in array:
    tk.Button(root, text=i, command=l(i)).pack()
```
could be a good workaround?

Comment: Nope, that will call the lambda inside the loop, which is not what you want.  That's exactly like `def l(i):` / `print_when_clicked(i)`.